# CSS Animation Won't Trigger a Second Time

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to make a little game. Kinda stupid, but I want there to be this random event that pops up and does a little CSS Keyframe animation. The end goal is to get it to pop up when the random event triggers, and then go away when the animation is over. When running the code, I can get it to work the first time, but the second time the animation doesn't trigger and only the text shows up. Any ideas?

```js
var myFood = document.getElementById("myFood");
var myWood = document.getElementById("myWood");
var myGold = document.getElementById("myGold");
var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var randomFoodEvent = document.getElementById("event");

var foodCount = 0;
var woodCount = 0;
var goldCount = 0;

myButton.addEventListener("click", buttonClick, false);

window.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler, false);

function keydownHandler(event) {
  console.log("keyCode = " + event.keyCode);
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    buttonClick();
  } else if (event.keyCode === 70) {
    foodCount++;
    myFood.innerHTML = "<strong>F</strong>ood: " + foodCount;
    var randomFoodNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    if (randomFoodNum === 50) {
      randomFoodEvent.className = "playEvent";
      randomFoodEvent.innerHTML = "Some villagers stole your food!";
      foodCount = foodCount - 25;
    }
  } else if (event.keyCode === 87) {
    woodCount++;
    myWood.innerHTML = "<strong>W</strong>ood: " + woodCount;
  } else if (event.keyCode === 71) {
    goldCount++;
    myGold.innerHTML = "<strong>G</strong>old: " + goldCount;
  }
}

randomFoodEvent.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
  randomFoodEvent.classList.remove = "playEvent";
  randomFoodEvent.innerHTML = "";
});

function buttonClick() {
  console.log("Button Clicked!");
  if ((foodCount >= 100) && (woodCount >= 100) && (goldCount >= 100)) {
    output.textContent = "You win!";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The animation code */

@keyframes example {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}


/* The element to apply the animation to */

.playEvent {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

```html
<h1>Buttons and Keyboard Events</h1>
<p id="output">
  Get 100 Food, 100 Wood, and 100 Gold to Win the Game!
</p>
<p id="myFood"><strong>F</strong>ood: 0</p>
<p id="myWood"><strong>W</strong>ood: 0</p>
<p id="myGold"><strong>G</strong>old: 0</p>

<p id="event">

</p>

<button id="myButton">Click Me to Win</button>
```

Sorry that there's a lot of code, I couldn't think of a better way to show what I'm trying to do without showing the whole thing.

Thanks!

EDIT: Heres a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8053pou1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error `randomFoodEvent.classList.remove("playEvent");`

```js
var myFood = document.getElementById("myFood");
var myWood = document.getElementById("myWood");
var myGold = document.getElementById("myGold");
var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var randomFoodEvent = document.getElementById("event");

var foodCount = 0;
var woodCount = 0;
var goldCount = 0;

myButton.addEventListener("click", buttonClick, false);

window.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler, false);

function keydownHandler(event) {
  console.log("keyCode = " + event.keyCode);
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    buttonClick();
  } else if (event.keyCode === 70) {
    foodCount++;
    myFood.innerHTML = "<strong>F</strong>ood: " + foodCount;
    var randomFoodNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    if (randomFoodNum === 50) {
      randomFoodEvent.className = "playEvent";
      randomFoodEvent.innerHTML = "Some villagers stole your food!";
      foodCount = foodCount - 25;
    }
  } else if (event.keyCode === 87) {
    woodCount++;
    myWood.innerHTML = "<strong>W</strong>ood: " + woodCount;
  } else if (event.keyCode === 71) {
    goldCount++;
    myGold.innerHTML = "<strong>G</strong>old: " + goldCount;
  }
}

randomFoodEvent.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
  randomFoodEvent.classList.remove("playEvent");
  randomFoodEvent.innerHTML = "";
});

function buttonClick() {
  console.log("Button Clicked!");
  if ((foodCount >= 100) && (woodCount >= 100) && (goldCount >= 100)) {
    output.textContent = "You win!";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The animation code */

@keyframes example {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}


/* The element to apply the animation to */

.playEvent {
  animation: example 4s 1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype.html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Keyboards and Buttons
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Buttons and Keyboard Events</h1>
  <p id="output">
    Get 100 Food, 100 Wood, and 100 Gold to Win the Game!
  </p>
  <p id="myFood"><strong>F</strong>ood: 0</p>
  <p id="myWood"><strong>W</strong>ood: 0</p>
  <p id="myGold"><strong>G</strong>old: 0</p>

  <p id="event">

  </p>

  <button id="myButton">Click Me to Win</button>
</body>

</html>
```